# How to fix 'Failed to execute goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:5.0.0:generateRunners (generateRunners)' error

Tags: maven, testing, cucumber

When I run feature in maven I receive error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:5.0.0:generateRunners (generateRunners) on project testProject: Execution generateRunners of goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:5.0.0:generateRunners failed: Parser errors:
[ERROR] (21:3): expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #StepLine, #TagLine, #ScenarioLine, #ScenarioOutlineLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Background:'
```

Is anyone knows how to solve that problem in maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a environment variable on the machine JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8